# How to make TextField unclickable/unfocusable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I have a simple `OutlinedTextField` with a label and text.
By the design, it should not be focused and/or typeable.
On the click event, the app should open a "picker" dialog and on a pick, the value of `TextField` should be updated.

So, as a result, the TextField, shouldn't:

- be focusable
- open keyboard
- accept text insertion or input
  It should:
- be clickable

As a backup option, I tried to make a simple `Text` look like an `OutlinedTextField` I think it is more difficult to make it look the same as `OutlinedTextField`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `enabled = false` to the [`OutlinedTextField`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#OutlinedTextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material.TextFieldColors))

> When `false`, the text field will be neither editable nor focusable, the input of the text field will not be selectable, visually text field will appear in the disabled UI state

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it
    },
    enabled = false
)
```

If you want to set custom colors for the disabled state just add:

```
    colors =  TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
        disabledTextColor = LocalContentColor.current.copy(LocalContentAlpha.current),
        disabledBorderColor =  MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
        disabledLabelColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(ContentAlpha.medium)
    )
```

Comment: In this case, it will look like disabled text? grey out? I don't want that

Comment: @Demigod just use the `colors` attribute to set your favorite colors

Comment: can you please advise how to change colors for material3? There are some changes...

Answer (score 0):

For Material 3 it could be like this:

```
colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
        disabledBorderColor = Color.LightGray,
        disabledTextColor = Color.LightGray,
        disabledLabelColor = Color.Gray,
        unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Gray,
        focusedBorderColor = Color.Black,
    )
```